# Does planting a sapling on farmland help it grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does planting a sapling on [Farmland](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Farmland) or or Damp Farmland help it grow into a bigger tree, or grow faster?

[image: Sapling on farmland]

Comment: I don't quite think so, but I have no way to actually deny this

Comment: I don't think so either, but it would involve looking at the code for sapling growth to be certain.

Comment: From anecdotal evidence, saplings on farmland don't grow at all, though this was rather a long time ago and could've been an SMP quirk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `BlockSapling.java`:

```
public void growTree(World world, int i, int j, int k, Random random)
    {
        int l = world.getBlockMetadata(i, j, k) & 3;
        world.setBlock(i, j, k, 0);
        Object obj = null;
        if(l == 1)
        {
            obj = new WorldGenTaiga2();
        } else
        if(l == 2)
        {
            obj = new WorldGenForest();
        } else
        {
            obj = new WorldGenTrees();
            if(random.nextInt(10) == 0)
            {
                obj = new WorldGenBigTree();
            }
        }
        if(!((WorldGenerator) (obj)).generate(world, random, i, j, k))
        {
            world.setBlockAndMetadata(i, j, k, blockID, l);
        }
    }
```

There is no reference to the block the sapling is planted on.

(While `world.getBlockMetaData(i, j, k)` looks suspicious, it is simply looking up what *kind* of tree the sapling should grow — pine, birch, or "normal".)

Comment: So can I plant saplings on cobblestone or obsidian or something goofy like that, and they'll grow?

Comment: @DoktorJ IIRC, it won't let you plant saplings on anything except dirt and farmland.  This code just grows a planted sapling, it doesn't determine where you can and cannot plant them. But, if you *could* plant it there, yes it would grow.